# How can I make my terminal text rainbow colored upon every boot up? (with lolcat)

Tags: terminal, zsh

I've been wondering how I could do some of these cool customization options for the terminal on a Mac and I came across [lolcat](https://github.com/busyloop/lolcat).

However, I can't seem to find an answer as to how to add this into my bashrc (FYI: I'm using zsh now just in case that makes a difference as to which file to add my customizations in) I have tried what many others have suggested, which was just typing `zsh | lolcat` into the terminal to get rainbow output in the current session, but I was wondering how I can have this every time I start a terminal session.

Also, I'm not sure if this is a bug or if there's something wrong with my terminal settings, but when I use a command with lolcat, I get an output like this:

```
karenlee@Karens-MBP ~ % Documents
Downloads
Library
Movies
Music
Pictures
Postman
Public
38;5;48m
karenlee@Karens-MBP ~ % 38;5;48m
```

The colors look right, but as you can see, when I type the `ls` command on the command line, it disappears and the output also gets messy. It also seems like there's extra lines of `38;5;48m` which are appearing. And it also seemed like many of the gems that are installed with lolcat have deprecated; is there another alternative to lolcat that plays nicely with macOS Catalina?

Comment: Are you sure that your terminal does support colors, and what is the value of your `TERMN` variable? If you type just `lolcat --help`, do you get coloured output?

Comment: @user1934428 Yes, when I type `lolcat -h`, I get the colored list of available options.

Comment: And if you then type `lolcat ~/.zshrc` in the same terminal, you do not see any colours????

Comment: @user1934428 When I type that command, I also see all the colored output.

Comment: So then, `lolcat` seems to work fine. What's the problem then?

Answer (score 0):

I made a shell extension for the world's fastest website generator that I make called [Nift](https://nift.dev). It has an easter egg where you can turn on lolcat output for most things with `lolcat.on` (after starting the shell with eg. `nift sh`). You will even get rainbow output when pressing tab to get possible completion options, I doubt you get that with any other suggested solutions.

The shell extension is for [f++](https://nift.dev/docs/f++.html) which is the in-built scripting language, which has [these](https://nift.dev/docs/fns.html) functions and [these](https://nift.dev/docs/types.html) types available. But anything it doesn't recognise is run as a system call using the (probably primary/default) shell on your machine (hence calling it a shell extension in REPL shell mode).

Nift will look for a version of lolcat installed on your machine and otherwise use an in-built version of it which should be the world's fastest (it's near identical to my c++ implementation [lolcat-cc](https://github.com/n-ham/lolcat-cc) which is the world's fastest). I highly recommend installing lolcat-cc (or another version of lolcat) on top of Nift though as otherwise you are frequently running the ~5mb Nift binary for basically all system calls, instead of a <1mb binary for lolcat.

f++ is somewhat of an interesting scripting language as well. Take [this](https://pastebin.com/5FM7Hzef) script for example which creates and deletes 100k empty text files. On my machine this runs in ~3.5 seconds whereas [this](https://pastebin.com/RTXXEHBg) Bash script doing essentially the same thing takes more like 3 minutes!! Some of the cool things you might already notice from that f++ script is you can expand variables inside strings, you can define variables with types, you can expand variables in to multiple parameters with function calls, you can have LOTS more than 10k input parameters for function calls (should be able to have millions!).

You can find some more information about the Nift REPLs (including shortcuts for different platforms) [here](https://nift.dev/docs/interactive.html).

If you need to define shell variables (not through f++ but the underlying shell) then you will need to do blocks of code using the sys/system function. You can also do blocks of code for Lua(JIT) and ExprTk similarly as they are both embedded in to Nift. You can use both Lua and ExprTk with accessing/modifying f++ variables as well..

So to get this shell (extension). Install Nift through a package manager or clone, make and install off GitHub. Enter `nift sh` in to your terminal to start the Nift f++ shell extension, then enter `lolcat.on` to turn on rainbow output.